# Prove the basic algebraic inequality used extensively everywhere.

Tags: functional-inequalities

How can I prove rigourously that if for any real numbers $x$ and $y$
(both are positive)

If $x \ge y$ then

This implies $x^n \ge y^n$ for any real $n$ as well.
(n is not negative)
This is used everywhere for example when n is half or two.

Is there a general result if $n$ is negative?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this inequality is only true for $n>0$.  If $n$ is negative then exponentiation is order-reversing.

Second, an outline of the proof goes something like this:

1. First, prove the result for whole number values of $n$. This can be done by induction, making use of the fact that multiplication by a positive number is order-preserving.
2. Next, use the result above to prove the inequality for $n$ of the form $1/m$, with $m$ a whole number.
3. Combine the two results to prove it is true for all positive rational exponents.
4. Use continuity to extend the definition to all positive real exponents.

Comment: Half greater than quarter and hence quarter greater than 1 by 16. How do you account for this ?

Comment: @RaghavSingal Quite true. The result does not require $x,y>1$, I'm not sure what I was thinking.  But it does require $n>0$.

Comment: How can we use continuity to prove for irrational as well can you elaborate ?

Comment: Depends on how you define $x^r$ for irrational $r$.  For example if $r$ is positive than one way to do it is as the supremum of $\{x^q | q \in \mathbb{Q}, 0 < q \le r$.  If that's your definition, then the inequality you want follows from the inequality for rational exponents.

Answer (score 0):

What if $y<x<-1 \cup n\mod 2 \equiv 0$? In that case, $x^n<y^n$, disproving the function.

Comment: What is mod ? I cant understand your sentence

Comment: If y and x are both negative but n is even

Comment: Yes you are correct sorry.

Comment: :D Add that parameter and that should do it

Comment: Btw nice observation if n is odd it always holds !

Comment: Also... what if $0<n<1$? In that case... ex: $\sqrt{4}<\sqrt{2}$ but $\sqrt{4}^\frac{1}{2}>\sqrt{2}^\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: That's incorrect square root 4 ie 2 cannot be greater than square root of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the strict monotonicity of $f(x)=\ln{x}$ then for any $n>0$ and for any $x,y>0$ we have WLOG
$$
x\ge y \iff \ln{x}\ge\ln{y} \iff n\ln{x}\ge n\ln{y} \iff \ln{x^n}\ge\ln{y^n} \iff x^n \ge y^n.
$$

Comment: So if n was negative the inequality would just always reverse ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Okay thanks is there some general rule for the case when only one of x and y is positive ?

Comment: Exponentials of negative number require the complex field in order to properly describe them. There might be a way to extend this proof with $x$ and/or $y$ being negative, but off the top of my head I don't know.